# Upload CSV to Google Drive Spreadsheet using Drive v2 Java API

Tags: java, spreadsheet, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a CSV as a Google spreadsheet

I do see that there is a request parameter convert=true available at

[Google Developer - insert.](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert)

Can some one help me on how to set this flag in Java API?

Answer (score 3):

The `Drive.Files.Insert` class has a `setConvert` method that you can use before calling `execute`. Using the [file.insert sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) as reference, you have to replace the following line:

```
File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
```

with:

```
File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).setConvert(true).execute();
```